# Keras Graph Execution Error When fitting the model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, lstm, convolutional-neural-network

I am using this https://keras.io/examples/vision/conv_lstm/ code and providing my own dataset, which consists of frame size 550x775. But When I try to execute the `model.fit` block it gives the following error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,550,775,32] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

I am assuming `[3,550,775,32]` is exhausting the colab GPU resources. Do I need to reduce the size of frames from `550x775` to `64x64`? Or is there a workaround because I can not afford to lower the frame dimensions.

Comment: you need more RAM or if you can't buy it then definitely you need to reduce your input size!

Comment: @MohammadAhmed by RAM you mean GPU RAM or System RAM?

Comment: It is mentioned there GPU RAM is exhausted...

Comment: @MohammadAhmed but google colab Tesla T4 has like ~15 gigs of RAM.

Comment: No, 12 GB of RAM and it cannot handle this much size, I have experienced it while training 3D image, for that you have to buy google COLAB Pro.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed what if I give it a try on some rtx 2000 series?

Comment: Well, the problem here is not here processing power but it needs a lot of RAM. so, use a graphic card with more RAM.